# How to pass a list of strings a sql parameter for the stored procedure to delete?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've got the following method that is supposed to delete the Holiday names from the database given from the List's that are passed in as arguments. The problem I am having is it isn't deleting anything from the database. Here is part of the method that I am having issues with:

```
private void RemoveGloOrderDays(List<SessionInfoList> sessionList, List<Holiday> selectedOrderHolidays, List<Holiday> selectedHolidays, List<string> orderDays, List<string> noOrderDays)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                {
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
                    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[RemoveGlobalOrderDays]";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SessionId", SqlDbType.Int);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SelectedOrderHolidays", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SelectedHolidays", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrderDays", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@NoOrderDays", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

                    connection.Open();

                    foreach (SessionInfoList session in sessionList)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters["@SessionId"].Value = session.SessionID;

                        cmd.Parameters["@SelectedOrderHolidays"].Value = DBNull.Value;
                        string joinedNames = string.Join(",", selectedOrderHolidays.Select(h => h.Name.Trim()));
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(joinedNames))
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters["@SelectedOrderHolidays"].Value = joinedNames;
                        }

                        cmd.Parameters["@SelectedHolidays"].Value = DBNull.Value;
                        joinedNames = string.Join(",", selectedHolidays.Select(h => h.Name.Trim()));
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(joinedNames))
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters["@SelectedHolidays"].Value = joinedNames;
                        }
```

Here is my stored procedure:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[RemoveGlobalOrderDays]') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[RemoveGlobalOrderDays]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RemoveGlobalOrderDays]
@SessionId int,
@SelectedHolidays nvarchar(500),
@SelectedOrderHolidays nvarchar(500),
@OrderDays nvarchar(500),
@NoOrderDays nvarchar(500)


WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE [cfgSchedule]
    SET
        [OrderDays] = @OrderDays,
        [NoOrderDays] = @NoOrderDays
    WHERE [cfgSchedule].[SessionId] = @SessionID

    DELETE FROM [SessionHolidayMapping]
    WHERE [HolidayName] = @SelectedHolidays
    AND
    [SessionId] = @SessionId

    DELETE FROM [SessionOrderHolidayMapping]
    WHERE [SessionId] = @SessionId
    AND
    [HolidayName] = @SelectedOrderHolidays

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you are passing list of names separated by comma and you want to delete all those names. You need to use IN operator to find all holiday names that should be deleted.

Here is an example how to do it for @SelectedHolidays:

```
declare @SelectedHolidays nvarchar(500) = 'H1,H2,H3'
declare @SelectedHolidaysXml xml = cast(replace(N'<R><I>' + @SelectedHolidays + N'</I></R>', ',', '</I><I>') as xml)


DELETE FROM [SessionHolidayMapping]
WHERE [HolidayName] in (select x.items.value('(.)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(500)') from @SelectedHolidaysXml.nodes('/R/I') as x(items))
AND [SessionId] = @SessionId
```

It is ugly, but I don't know of better way to split comma separated values in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using nvarchar, you could use table valued parameters for the parameters @Selectedholidays and @selectedorderholidays and then something like

```
DELETE [SessionHolidayMapping] FROM [SessionHolidayMapping] A
    Inner join @selectedholidays S
    On A.[HolidayName] = S.Holidayname where A.[SessionId] = @SessionId.
```

The "HolidayName" is one column of the parameter.

I'm on my phone and cannot test it appropriately.